# 3 MYSQL query using 1 query and limit

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my php code:

```
 $trsql = "SELECT * from members order by id desc";
  $trresult = mysql_query($trsql);
  $count = mysql_num_rows($trresult);
  while ($trrow = mysql_fetch_array($trresult)) {
  $bill_membertotal = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM billing WHERE suite='$trrow[suite]' order by bill_id desc limit 1"); 
  $bill_membercount = mysql_fetch_array($bill_membertotal);
  $check_membertotal = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(net) AS checker FROM billing WHERE suite='$trrow[suite]'"); 
  $check_membercount = mysql_fetch_assoc($check_membertotal);

echo $trrow['col1'] $trrow['col2'] $trrow['col1'] $bill_membercount['balance']  $check_membercount['checker'] ;
}
```

**member table:**
[id suite col1 col2 col 3]
**billing table:**
[bill_id suite gross fee net balance]

Question: How to make this 3 query using 1 query? I know about MYSQL Join function. But how to do in this case?

Comment: Can you post your db schema and the expected reporting columns required, then it would be easy to demonstrate using JOINs

Comment: **rsakhale** posted thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would seem to give the expected result; since you only want the last bill for one field and MySQL doesn't have analytic functions, a subquery will solve that field easier than a join.

```
SELECT id member_id, col1, col2, col3,
  (SELECT balance 
   FROM billing b1 
   WHERE b1.suite=m.suite 
   ORDER BY bill_id DESC LIMIT 1) balance,
   SUM(net) AS checker
FROM members m
LEFT JOIN billing b
  ON m.suite = b.suite
GROUP BY col1,col2,col3,id
ORDER BY id DESC
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ac3f/4).

Comment: I am new in php. Your script works on sqlfifle great but I can not print result in my php script.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * , 
        (select count(*) from members) as members_count,
        (select count(*) from billing where suite = bill.suite) as bill_count,
        (select count(*) from billing where suite = check.suite) as check_count,
from members members
inner join billing  bill on members.suite = bill.suite
inner join billing check members.suite = check.suite
```

Comment: you can use group by after according to what data you need, the query I just wrote will return all the information of the 3 queries of yours

Comment: don't need one. you will receive a column with the value of the total you need. this means that each row will contain the value of all 3 totals you need.

Comment: @zionbenyacov If you look at the original queries, it's not the counts they're after.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested:

```
$query = "SELECT
    `member`.`col1` AS `col1`,
    `member`.`col2` AS `col2`,
    `bill`.`balance` AS `balance`,
    SUM(`bill`.`net`) AS `checker`
FROM
    `members` AS `member`,
    `billing` AS `bill`,
WHERE
    `bill`.`suite`=`member`.`suite`
ORDER BY
    `member`.`id`,
    `bill`.`bill_id`
DESC";
$results    = mysql_query($query);
$count      = mysql_num_rows($results);

while($entry = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
    printf('%s, %s, %s, %s, %s', $entry['col1'], $entry['col2'], $entry['col1'], $entry['balance'], $entry['checker']);
}
```

**mysql_*** is marked **deprecated**

Comment: if you need an LIMIT, add these? Show no initiative! Urgh.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but give a try on this as this is what is expected by your report

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ccc6/3

Query:

```
SELECT m.*, COUNT(b.id) as member_count, SUM(net) as checker
FROM member m
JOIN billing b ON m.suite = b.suite
GROUP BY b.suite
```

Comment: Can you update the above sql fiddle with the actual table schema and some example values :)

Comment: @MoyedAnsari - the `member` table written in the query was with respect to the tables created in sqlfiddle